# Rotate a GLUT bitmap/stroke string around its center?

Tags: java, opengl, glut, jogl, opengl-compat

As you can see on the pictures the string rotates around its origin.

### No rotation:

[image: No rotation]

### Rotated:

[image: Rotated]

Changing the RasterPos or translate it does not change this at all. I tried **glutStrokeString** and **glutBitmapString**. The code for the example:

```
gl.glColor4f((float) 1, (float) 0, (float) 0, 1.0f);
gl.glScalef(0.0015f, 0.0015f, 0.0015f);
gl.glRotatef(-angleHorizontal, 0, 1, 0);
glut.glutStrokeString(GLUT.STROKE_ROMAN, "ABCDEF");
```

Answer (score 1):

## glutBitmapCharacter:

You can't. It makes use of the (outdated, deprecated, legacy) OpenGL bitmap operations, which are always aligned to the pixel grid.

## glutStrokeCharacter:

These are just regular line segments that transform through the fixed function pipeline; or if you're in a compatibility profile through an early GLSL version shader program that uses the set of built-in variables to access the fixed function pipeline state. In one of my codesamples programs (which I wrote to explain how the projection frustum works) I have some helper function to draw arrows with annotations. You can find the full code here https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/blob/master/samples/OpenGL/frustum/frustum.c the relevant function starts in line 114.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I'm using glutStrokeString now. And I fixed it. I don't know exactly how but it works :3

Comment: Then, my suggestion in your previous question was correct.